# How to use js noty plugin, which is under the vendor in CakePHP?

Tags: javascript, css, cakephp, composer-php, noty

I installed the noty javascript plugin with the composer.

`composer require needim/noty`

It installed the plugin under the /vendor/needim/noty.
I would like to use the /vendor/needim/noty/lib/noty.css, and /vendor/needim/noty/lib/noty.js. How can I find them from the default ctp with HTML helpers, and load them? Or should I just copy this files into the web root and use them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loading javascript files from the vendors in CakePHP 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26736656/loading-javascript-files-from-the-vendors-in-cakephp-3)

Comment: Vendors exists outside the scope of the `webroot`. You either have to use a controller to send the file manually, or you copy the files as part of your install/build process. Traditionally, it's a build problem.